# Will there be any legal consequence if I ignore a bill that I do not owe?

Tags: united-states, medical, bills

I received a bill from my doctor's office for a copay of $25 that I do not need to pay. I called the office and they acknowledged that it was a mistake. However, for the past few months, they still send me this bill once in a while. I feel frustrated to call them again regarding their mistake.

Since I do not owe them money as this bill is a mistake, will there be any legal consequence if I simply ignore it?

Answer (score -3):

Worst case, your "debt" can be handed to a collection agency which will be a pain for you, even if you are not owing them anything. From a practical point of view, I would first demand that they acknowledge the mistake in writing, and the next time ask a lawyer to write a letter for you and charge them for it.

Comments: Why "Ask a lawyer to write a letter and charge for it". A lawyer will know what to put in the letter so they have to pay him his fee, because they are asking for money that they have no right to. Clearly someone doesn't care about the inconvenience of it all to you. Once they have to pay $100 for this letter, they will care and make sure the inconvenience to you goes away. Their boss will ask someone "What is going on here? Why are we paying $100?" and someone has to say "because we asked a customer repeatedly for $25 even after telling him, including in writing, that he doesn't owe us anything."

Comment: Why ask a lawyer to write a letter?

Comment: If you have to ask (the OP), you don't understand the law well-enough to know what should go in the letter. Anyhow, the actual question is a request for information about the law, and the suggestion "ask your lawyer" is a standard Law SE admonition to not even *appear* to ask for legal advice.

Comment: Indeed, there's a big difference between legal consequences and practical consequences. Legally they can't do anything, in practice, they might report you to a credit reference agency or even send round a debt collector/bailiff who might unlawfully try to collect.

Comment: And the debt collector/bailiff would have no idea that you don't actually owe the money, and they have experience to get money from people who don't want to pay.

Comment: To get acknowledgement of the mistake in writing, try e-mailing instead of calling.  The more convenient it is for them, the sooner you'll have your written evidence, and "reply to" an email is as fast and convenient as written messages get.

Comment: no lawyer will accept a third party's potential future payment for services.